# View into the source code of an ethereum smart contract

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

the whole system of ethereum smart contract relies on trust. 
You can be 100% percent sure that a smart contract will get executed when the conditions are met.

But how can i assure that the smart contract itself isn't a fraud?
Is it possible to look into the source code of each executed block? Every block is f.e. listed  here https://www.etherchain.org/

Is it possible to look into the bytecode of each smart contract deployed on the ethereum blockchain?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Clicking around for 5 seconds, and I'm finding stuff like this: https://www.etherchain.org/account/2a0c0dbecc7e4d658f48e01e3fa353f44050c208#code

Comment: I was looking for source code in a block. You went to the "account" view, which is absolutely logical and the perfect answer for my question. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the author's decision to make the smart contract code of open.